# Getting DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when scanning bigtable using Hbase client

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, hbase-client

I am getting the following error when scanning a large number of rows(~1 million) based on a prefix

> Status{code=DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, description=deadline exceeded:
>   -646391190127 ns from now, cause=null}

Could someone suggest what are the `BigtableOptions` I should configure so that I don't see the DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error. I have tried setting `BIGTABLE_RPC_TIMEOUT_MS_KEY` and `BIGTABLE_LONG_RPC_TIMEOUT_MS_KEY` to large values but still getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried changing the [BIGTABLE_READ_RPC_TIMEOUT_MS_KEY](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableOptionsFactory.html#BIGTABLE_READ_RPC_TIMEOUT_MS_KEY)?

Comment: yup tried setting that as well

Comment: I honestly think that the issue is more related to the way you designed your schema. Have you taken into consideration the best practices mentioned here : https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#row-key-prefixes . Are you using any type of keys mentioned in "row keys to avoid" rubric ?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution?